# stuck in preparing automatic repair loop windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot

my boot drive is a 1TB HDD + 16GB optane memory, SATA mode was set to intel RST

it suddenly wont boot this morning and got stuck in stuck in preparing automatic repair loop

so i disabled optane memory is bios(took 30 minutes), then i set SATA mode to AHCI and it still wont boot

i looked into several solution, so far non of them are working

tried bootrec /fixboot and it gave me access is denied

i also tried another know good hdd and what's strange is it wont boot unless i change SATA mode back to Intel RST

Please help

Comment: One the problem machine / hard drive, when it wants to stick in the loop, it should offer you some options. One of these is a Reset Option. Make sure your data is backed up and do Reset. This should get you started.

Comment: i tried everything in the recovery mode, it wont even boot into safe mode

Comment: Back up your drive and do a fresh install of Windows. That is about all that is left now.

Comment: Possible fixes here>>>>>https://www.technology.org/2017/11/14/7-ways-fix-stuck-in-windows-automatic-repair-loop/

Comment: Boot from a W10 install DVD or usb to do repairs.